# (image) under the text or below the text?

Tags: word-choice

#1 Background image **under** the text

#2 Background image **bellow** the text

Which is correct in the context of computer screens ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of a background image, neither **under** nor **below** are common. **Under** *could* work, but usually it isn't used in that way; **below** would not work, because it implies that the image is lower *vertically on the page* (y-axis) rather than *deeper in the screen* (z-axis).

Instead, I would say that the background image is **beneath** or **underneath** the text.